# AgentPy and GIS

Tags: gis, agent-based-modeling, agentpy

I am planning on developing an agent-based model with AgentPy, but I would like to include a GIS extension. Generally, I would like to have the agents move from one polygon to another. Does anyone know how to add a GIS extension to AgentPy? Or are there any resources you know of that may help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly easier to use [Mesa](https://www.gisagents.org/2020/05/utilizing-python-for-agent-based.html).